# Appcelerator Android 6 - My app will not run on android 6 device

Tags: android, appcelerator

My application will not run on android 6 devices.

I'm running 5.1.2 GA

Here's the stacktrace:

```
-- Start application log ----------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] : TiApplication: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, app created. 
[INFO] : TiApplication: (main) [170,170] Titanium 5.1.2 (2015/12/16 19:00 ca822b2) 
[INFO] : DatabaseHelper: No value in database for platform key: 'unique_machine_id' returning supplied default '' 
[INFO] : DatabaseHelper: No value in database for platform key: 'hardware_machine_id' returning supplied default '' 
[ERROR] : linker: readlink('/proc/self/fd/23') failed: Permission denied [fd=23] 
[ERROR] : linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/app/com.lilypadsolutions.lilypadappV2-1/lib/arm/libstlport_shared.so". Will use given name. 
[INFO] : TiApplication: (main) [292,462] Titanium Javascript runtime: v8 
[ERROR] : linker: readlink('/proc/self/fd/23') failed: Permission denied [fd=23] 
[ERROR] : linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/app/com.lilypadsolutions.lilypadappV2-1/lib/arm/libkroll-v8.so". Will use given name. 
[INFO] : TiRootActivity: (main) [1,1] checkpoint, on root activity create, savedInstanceState: null 
[INFO] : TiApplication: (main) [3,4] Analytics have been disabled 
[WARN] : TiTempFileHelper: (main) [2,6] The external temp directory doesn't exist, skipping cleanup 
[WARN] : V8Object: (KrollRuntimeThread) [16,22] Runtime disposed, cannot set property 'userAgent' 
[ERROR] : linker: readlink('/proc/self/fd/23') failed: Permission denied [fd=23] 
[ERROR] : linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/app/com.lilypadsolutions.lilypadappV2-1/lib/arm/libti.styledlabel.so". Will use given name. 
[INFO] : Process: Sending signal. PID: 13026 SIG: 9
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide more information about the app itself. Are you using any modules (e.g. styledlabel is mentioned in the error message; try running without). Also try to run "ti clean" and build it again. Does it work without any changes on android 5/android 4 devices?

Comment: Yes it works every-time on my android 5 devices. I updated ti.imagefactor and ti.cloudpush....still same results

Comment: And i removed style label..as i wasn't using

Comment: I'm having the same error. Any solution? Is very very urgent

Answer (score 0):

Please use [latest build](http://builds.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#master) always. you can reduce error.

```
appc ti sdk install --branch master 6.0.0.v20160119083154
```

the above command is for latest build.

Answer (score 0):

With Android 6.0 they have changed the permissions...

So, I suggest you have a look at the [Titanium 5.1.0 Sample app](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2015/11/titanium-5-1-0-sample-app/). Specifically, I suggest you have a look at the [permissions.js file](https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/appc-sample-ti510/blob/master/app/controllers/permissions.js) as one of the errors in the stack trace is:

```
[ERROR] : linker: readlink('/proc/self/fd/23') failed: Permission denied [fd=23]
```

HTH

/John